# Need help defining a function in python

Tags: python

I need to code a get_input function that has loop validation so the number cannot be less than 0
This is the program. ive made this a global function but my instructor told me it was wrong. Making `get_input` a global function seems to work but i need to use the means of

```
def get_input():

get_input()
```

Ive been setting up the global function as get_input = input just because i have no clue how to do what i posted above without geting the error "global name is not defined".

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
get_input = input

def main():
    pennies = get_input("Enter pennies : ")
    nickels = get_input("Enter nickels : ")
    dimes = get_input("Enter dimes : ")
    quarters = get_input("Enter quarters : ")

    print("You entered : ")
    print("\tPennies  : " , pennies)
    print("\tNickels  : " , nickels)
    print("\tDimes    : " , dimes)
    print("\tQuarters : " , quarters)


    total_value = get_total(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters)
    dollars = get_dollars(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters)
    left_over_cents = get_left_over_cents(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters)

    print("Total = $", total_value, sep="")
    print("You have", dollars, "dollars and", left_over_cents, "cent(s)")

main()
```

Comment: Please show one or more of your attempts and we'll be able to help you.

Comment: So where *is* your definition of `get_input`? There are no syntax errors in what you've posted. You might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/3001761) useful.

Comment: You have added more explanation but it is still not clear where you are defining `get_input`. It will be easier if you can post the whole programme including the definition of `get_input`.

Comment: Just want to let everyone know that i have just gotten into coding about a week ago so i have very little knowledge in this. I am not looking for a answer but more of guidance to the answer so i can learn how to do it.

Comment: Make sure you define your get_input function before calling `main()`. Then you should not get any error concerning the global name.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to just put all your raw_input statements inside your get_input function.

```
def get_input(currency):
   currency = -1.0     
   while currency < 0:
       try:
           currency = float(raw_input("Enter %s:  ", % (currency)))
       except ValueError:
           print "Invalid input!"
           currency = -1.0
           continue
       if currency < 0:
           print "Can't have negative money!"
       else:
           return currency

def main():
    pennies = get_input("pennies")
    nickles= get_input("nickles")
    dimes= get_input("dimes")
    quarters= get_input("quarters")
```

Then so on with your program

Comment: Syntax error on the line  currency = float(raw_input("Enter %s:  ", % (currency)))

Comment: I wrote this from memory.  Take out that comma and it should be okay.